# Constrain a number of factors in Design of Experiments

Tags: experiment-design, split-plot

I have multiple factors with multiple levels, for which I am trying design of experiments.

Here is an example:

```
A:1,2,3
B:1,2
C:1,2,3,4
D:1,2,3,4,5
E:1,2
F:1,2,3,4
...
Z:1,2
```

where A,B,C,... are the factors, 1,2,3,... are the levels. The level 1 of each factor is essentially a base-level (meaning no change from some default value). For the resulting experiment runs I need to ensure that only less than a certain number of factors are tried at a time.

Here is an example:

```
A B C D E F ... Z
1 1 2 1 1 4 ... 1
2 1 1 3 1 1 ... 1
...
```

In this example, only two factors are allowed to change at a time. This is just an example to illustrate the idea.

Does anybody know how to practically design such experiments? I am trying AlgDesign R package, which has optMonteCarlo() function to find a design. It is possible to provide constraints in that function but if I want only a small number of factors, the function becomes highly inefficient and can't find any design. I believe there must be specialized type of DOE and would appreciate any pointers.

**Edit:**

In my particular optimization problem there are ~100 factors with multiple levels but I would like to change less than 10 factors at a time. The experimental unit in my case is a certain biological object for which I cannot change more than 10 factors at a time. I am not looking at One-Factor-At-a-Time (OFAT) type of experiments but I need to limit the number of factors that change simultaneously.

Comment: You might not see many people discussing this type of design because it's not very efficient. See this less formal explainer here: http://mescal.imag.fr/membres/arnaud.legrand/teaching/2011/EP_czitrom.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I have updated my post to better explain what I am trying to achieve. I am not actually looking into OFAT experiments but just need to limit the number of factors that can change simultaneously.

Comment: You could look into slit-plot designs, see https://www.minitab.com/en-us/Published-Articles/DOE--Handling-Hard-to-Change-Factors-with-Split-Plot-Designs-in-Minitab/